# How to scale and repeat image with Python?

Tags: python

I would like to scale a bpy.data.images, the goal is to replace the pixels of the image with those of the same scaled and repeated image, for example scaled down by half, so the repetition will be 4 times

I know I could do something with image.pixels, but doing various tests, it's too slow.

I was wondering if there was a function in Blender that does this, otherwise I could create one myself, but I wanted to avoid using the PIL module.

Note, I'm not talking about scaling images in blender nodes, that's simple. I'm talking about scaling the pixels directly on the image.

The basic function I set up is this:

```
def stamp_image_to_another(from_img, to_img, scale_factor=2):
    # This is just an example where I copy pixels from one image to another while maintaining the aspect ratio of the target image
 
    if from_img.size != to_img.size:
        # To simplify the size calculation (i hope)
        temp_img = from_img.copy()
        temp_img.scale(to_img.size[0], to_img.size[1])
        to_img.pixels = temp_img.pixels[:]

        bpy.data.images.remove(temp_img)
    else:
        to_img.pixels = from_img.pixels[:]
```

Comment: could you provide a sample screenshot of the original image and the output image you want? sorry but i dont understand your goal. so maybe screenshots or drawings will help clarify.